# How do I mock out objects used in the constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, karma-runner

I have some legacy JavaScript code that I am trying to write some unit tests for - I use Jasmine for that. The classes looks like the below example. Some public methods, but also with some code which gets executed when the file is loaded - I guess it could be considered the constructor of the class.

```
var Overview = (function(){
  HubStarter.wait("Overview");
  var exports = {};
  exports.Format = function(value){
    //some code
  };
  return exports;
})();
```

When I run the tests in Visual Studio with ReSharper, I get no errors. But when I run the tests with Karma I get some errors because of some code is being run when the JavaScript file is loaded - the code calls some methods on undefined objects.
I have no problem testing the Format method on the Overview object, but HubStarter is undefined. I haven't added the HubStarter.js file to karma.conf.js because that file is dependent on a lot of other things.

Is there any way to mock out the HubStarter object when it is being called so early in the execution?